# Where is Install via USB in Samsung phone

Tags: android-studio, samsung-mobile, samsung

When I am running Android Studio play button it is throwing me this error:

> Installation did not succeed.
> The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED
> Installation via USB is disabled.